# SQL Activation & Userdata Update

Tags: php, sql, database, activation

I'm currently developing a PHP form that has the following fields:

- First Name
- List item
- Last Name
- Date of Birth
- Email Address
- Select your Favourite Bar
- Company Name
- Activation Number (Hidden)
- User Number (Hidden)

I'm trying to get the PHP form to do the following:

- Check the Activation Number hasn't been activated
- If hasn't been activated insert all fields into the usernumber sql database
- After submitted form disactivate users Activatin Number

I've managed to get the activation working but I cant seem to get the php to check for activation and insert the fields into the correct areas.

[image: SQL Screenshot]

This is the current database, if anyone could advice me on how to get the PHP to do the above that would be fantastic.

Comment: So how is activation discativated? Set to null, same as or not same as checkactivation. PS the code you have now would help.

Comment: Currently they is two forms, Form one checks thats the Username and Password are not Activated (Check_Activation) and allows you to move onto form two, if the Check_Activation matches the Activation number then it displays an error message. I just need form to to be able to insert the users details into the correct username.

Here is the link - http://awkreativ.com/freelance/analogue/barrio/

Comment: I'm currently working with 
update members SET `EmailAddress` = 'adam@test.com', `First Name` = 'Adam' where username = 100001;
Seems to be doing the second part of the job.

Comment: Got the fields updating, 

UPDATE `members` SET `First Name` = 'Adam', `Last Name` = 'Wadsworth', `D.O.B` = '1988-09-21', `EmailAddress` = 'adam@awkreativ.com', `Favourite` = 'East', `Company Name` = 'AWK' WHERE `Username` = 100001;